# MySql query updating multiple fields based on a set of filters?

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 tables, `adNote` and `bookSlotItem`. I currently have a problem where the `adNote` table is missing a value for `storyId` in multiple rows.

The good thing is that the `bookSlotItem` table has all correct values for `storyId`.

I am trying to write a query that will basically update `adNote.storyId` with the values from `bookSlotItem.storyId`. But, I only want to do so if `adNote.storyId` does not have a value and `adNote.storyTaskTypeClass=2`. I would like to use the `processId` value from each table row in order to match them correctly.

So in the example below, the row with `processId` `124` within the `adNote` table would assume a `storyId` value of `202` because it has a `storyTaskTypeClass` of `2` and the `storyId` value was missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, any helpful links would be great.

**adNote Table**

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════╗══════════════════╗
║ processId ║    storyId   ║storyTaskTypeClass║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣══════════════════╣
║    123    ║              ║         1        ║
║    124    ║              ║         2        ║
║    125    ║      203     ║         2        ║
║    126    ║      204     ║         2        ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

**bookSlotItem Table**

```
╔═══════════╦══════════════╗
║ processId ║    storyId   ║
╠═══════════╬══════════════╣
║    123    ║      201     ║
║    124    ║      202     ║
║    125    ║      203     ║
║    126    ║      204     ║
╚═══════════╩══════════════╝
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help...

Comment: How are the tables adNote and bookSlotItem related? Is there an ID field that is the same?

Comment: @sgeddes I have udpated my question with better details.

Comment: @Michael Yes, I have updated my question showing that they have matching processId fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to `update` with a `join`:

```
update adnote a 
join bookSlotItem b on a.processid = b.processid 
set a.storyid = b.storyid
where a.storyTaskTypeClass = 2
      and a.storyid is null
```

Comment: This seems to work well. I ran it on my local version which has a much smaller number of rows that I can test on. I don't see where you take into account the fact that I only want to update when the storyId is blank though. I would like to only update the rows that I have to if that is possible.

Comment: Would I just place `WHERE a.storyId = ''` right below the last line?

Comment: @jmchauv -- sorry, I missed that when reading your question.  Don't use `where` again, but rather use `and`.  Also are the values `''` or `null`? I assume that's an integer and not a varchar -- in which case, you should be using `and a.storyid is null`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query that should work for you. I've used a similar query before.

```
UPDATE an
JOIN bookSlotItem bsi 
ON an.processId = bsi.processId
SET an.storyId = bsi.storyId
FROM adNote an  
WHERE an.storyId = '' 
AND an.storyTaskTypeClass = 2
```

Basically, you need to combine the tables and perform an `UPDATE` based on the combined table values.

Comment: Hm, I received a sql syntax error warning whenever running this one.

Comment: This is not the correct syntax for `mysql`.  The `join` clause should come before the `set` clause.

Comment: @sgeddes Thanks for the correction! Now it's edited.